# Defining object edges in images matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I am using matlab 2016a

Is there any function in the matlab version I am using that will provide me with the same information that is obtained by using the findContours function (with mode=CV_RETR_TREE) from OpenCV?

[OpenCV findContours Function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#void%20findContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20OutputArray%20hierarchy,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20Point%20offset%29)

Comment: First question: what is the matlab version you are using?

Comment: Sorry it was written earlier 2016a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a similar function in matlab would be [bwboundaries](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html)

Comment: From when I tried using bwboundaries it gave me the square boundaries of my objects not the tight form boundaries around the actual shape, which is what I am looking for

Comment: What do you mean by square boundaries? Did you use the 8-connected (default) version?

Comment: I did. But I will retry. Thank you! And I meant that it defined the boundaries not as the pixel by pixel boundaries but a general boundary defined by the boundary points that would make a square around the object, not the shape that the object actually is (strange shapes that the brain can be in a mri scan)

Comment: from my experience `bwboundaries` gives the "tight" pixel-by-pixel boundaries. you can reduce it to main "anchor points" using fex entries like [Polygon Simplification](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45342-polygon-simplification) or [Decimate Polygon](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34639-decimate-polygon). And please consider accept this answer if it helped you.